# Why can $|\Psi (t=0)\rangle $ be written as a coherent superposition of some eigenkets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, schroedinger-equation, superposition

Why can $|\Psi (t=0)\rangle $ be written as a coherent superposition of some eigenkets?

One of the approaches to solve time dependent Schrodinger equation $i\hbar \frac{\partial |\Psi(t)\rangle}{\partial t} = \hat{H} |\Psi(t)\rangle $ is to solve the time-independent part $\hat{H} |\Psi\rangle = E |\Psi\rangle $ and using the eigen vectors & eigen values, find the $ |\Psi(t)\rangle $.
In this we make use of the time propagator $\mathcal{U}(t,t_o)$ that acts on   $|\Psi (t=0)\rangle $.

So, when we write $|\Psi (t)\rangle = \mathcal{U}(t,t_o)  \ |\Psi(0)\rangle $ whys is it that we can write the wavefunction at t=0 as coherent superposition of eigen states of the time-independent schrodinger equation.

Comment: the propagator $U(t,t_0)$ acts on $| \psi(t_0) \rangle$ and not $| \psi(0) \rangle$

Answer (score 2):

If we use Hermetian operators then we are guaranteed that the eigenvectors of the operator can form a complete orthogonal basis.

Comment: But why does the time independent equation yield a complete orthogonal basis for t=0 case only

Comment: @EverydayFoolish I'm not sure I understand. Are you asking why $t=0$ is used instead of $t=1$ for example? This is true for all times

Comment: Ok, so at any time it's a superposition of eigen states but the amplitudes of each state vary with time giving rise to dynamics of the system.

Comment: @EverydayFoolish Yes that's right

Comment: @EverydayFoolish It's not the variation of the amplitudes with time, but the variations of the phases with time that produce the dynamics.

Comment: @EverydayFoolish It is quite beautiful to imagine what Buzz said in their comment. You see each eigenket is an eigenket of the Hamiltonian. Thus, $e^{-i\hat{H}t}|E_n\rangle=e^{-iE_nt}|E_n\rangle$. So, all that time-evolution would do is make the phase of each of the component eigenket linearly increase with time with the rate of increase being the energy $E_n$ of each corresponding eigenket.

Comment: Then if we invoke such a concept, how do we explain the geometric phase that the system picks up? How is the geometric phase related to this?

Comment: @Buzz yes you are right. I figured the OP just meant the entire coefficient was changing with time, but it is more precise to specify that it's just the phase that is changing.

Answer (score 0):

The Schrodinger equation is a first order equation in time, hence we need an initial condition for the wave function $\psi(\textbf{r},t=0)$ to solve for later time. The wave function at time $t=0$ is a superposition of whatever you want since it is arbitrary, like the initial position and velocity in classical mechanics. However, it is more practical to express it in the basis of the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian.